# add multiple fields using AddFieldAsXml in csom

Tags: 2013, office-365, csom, 2016, addfieldasxml

is it possible to add multiple fields at one go in SharePoint CSOM?

I tried

```
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);

            string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='NewField' Name='NewField' /><Field Type='Note' DisplayName='NewNote' Name='NewNote' />";
            FieldCollection collField = list.Fields;
            collField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
```

It didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Specifying in 1 single schema won't work. You can write as many schemas and AddFieldAsXml as you want one after the other for the number of columns you want to enter.
When you execute the query after all the "AddFieldAsXml", it is executed as **ONE CALL** only.

Refer this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9fde685-b35c-466c-8898-7b87707006d2/add-multiple-columns-to-a-library-online-sharepoint?forum=sharepointdevelopment